# A function that reverses a string using a loop

Tags: python, string, loops, reverse, python-2.x

```
def main():
    print(reverseString("Hello"))

def reverseString(string):
    newString=""
    for i in range(len(string)-1,-1):
        newString+=string[i]
    print newString

main()
```

I tried running this code but nothing is printed and I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a school assignment, or other sort of exercise. But if you want to know a quick way to reverse a string: `print( string[::-1] )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is missing the step of `-1` in the `range()`:

```
for i in range(len(string)-1, -1, -1):
```

Without the step the `for` loop immediately exits, leaving `newstring` as `''`.

BTW: you are not returning anything from `reverseString()` so:

```
print(reverseString("Hello"))
```

Will print `None`, which I assume is not wanted. You probably want to:

```
return newString
```

in `reverseString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Because your reverseString method doesnt have a return value. try removing print in your main method.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
def main():
    print(reverseString("Hello"))


def reverseString(string):
    newString=""
    for i in range(len(string)):
        newString+=string[len(string)-i-1]
    return newString

main()
```